# Invalid argument in C using vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am new to `C` programming, and have two questions on compiling an existing `C` program using `vscode`.

The header of C program (i.e., test.c) includes the following `h` file.

```
#include <failure.h>
```

Even though the failure.h is in the same folder as test.c, the vscode gives the following error,

```
test.c:2:30: fatal error: failure.h: No such file or directory
 #include <failure.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
```

After changing  #include <failure.h>  into `#include "failure.h"`  Looks like it does not complain the "no such file or directory". But
I got the following error message instead. How to understand this error message, or how to compile with arguments?

```
cc1.exe: fatal error: test.c: Invalid argument
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: You will need to show your codes for anyone to know what's going on.

Comment: @ kaylum, thanks for sharing the related thread.

Comment: Please don't tag c++ in c questions unless you are really using both languages